# How to pick a Lyapunov Function and make asymptotically stable?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Dynamics I have ,
$$\dot{x_1} = x_2$$

$$\dot{x_2} = u$$
if I pick Lyapunov function
$$V(x) = \frac{1}{2}*x^2_1 + \frac{1}{2}*x^2_2$$
then

$$\dot{V(x)} = x_1*\dot{x_2} +x_2*u$$

and

$$u = -x_1 -x_2$$
$$ \dot{V(x)} = -x^2_2 \leq 0 $$
But this in not asymptotically stable.
How to make it ?
Either we can change u or V(x)
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pick the control law as follows

$$
u(x) = -x_1 - x_2 - \frac{x_1^2}{x_2},
$$

but that is not well defined when $x_2=0$.

Instead one could make use of the fact that your proposed control law makes the system dynamics linear, with

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x,
$$

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

A Lyapunov function for such system can be found of the form

$$
V(x) = x^\top P\,x,
$$

with $P$ positive definite which satisfies the [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)

$$
A^\top P + P\,A = -Q,
$$

with $Q$ positive definite. If $A$ is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix#Hurwitz_stable_matrices) any positive definite $Q$ should also yield a corresponding positive definite $P$.

For example when setting $Q$ equal to the identity matrix yields

$$
V(x) = \frac{1}{2} (3\,x_1^2+2\,x_1\,x_2+2\,x_2^2) = \frac{1}{2} (2\,x_1^2+(x_1+x_2)^2+x_2^2),
$$

$$
\dot{V}(x) = -x_1^2 - x_2^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can proceed with this control law except when x_2 becomes zero. The second procedure is helpful, I will try to proceed with that and see what happens. Thank You